# R fwrite separates a dataframe entry that has commas

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, data.table, fwrite

I am thinking of using `fwrite` from the development version of data.table to write large dataframes to `csv` files fast. However, it seems to separate whatever goes after a comma into a separate column (not desired) while `write.csv` does not do that (as desired). Here is an example.

```
# Install data.table 1.9.7
remove.packages("data.table")                         # First remove the current version
install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
    repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table") # Then install devel version

library(data.table)
x <- c('a1, b1, c1', 'a2, b2, c2')
y <- c(1, 2)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
fwrite(df, 'fwrite.csv')
write.csv(df, 'write.csv')
```

If you look at the file written by `fwrite`, you will see the b's and c's are separated into separate columns (not desired) while that does not happen in the file written by `write.csv` (as desired). Does anyone know how to help `fwrite` not do that? Thank you.

Comment: I get ...`Error: could not find function "fwrite"`

Comment: Use `quote=TRUE` arg to fwrite

Comment: @42- upgrade to latest devel

Comment: The suggestion of using `quote=TRUE` by Frank @Frank above works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Filed [#1838](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/1838) since this issue hurt me as well. See the discussion on [#1664](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1664) for more.